# Supermarket parts

Tags: single-word-requests

What do we call those part or section that we put products in Supermarkets?
I just find `shelf` and `rack`. but I think shelf is the small part of the big section. What do we call those?

I marked them as 1 and 2 in the image.[image]

Comment: Maybe you know the term used in your language? If you do, try translating it into English and see what you get. Personally, I think *supermarket shelf /ves*  works just fine.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There is no word in my language for those. I want a word for a section and name for each part of that section.

Comment: In your shoes, I would find an image online, number the different parts I'd like to know the word of and upload the image IN my question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks, I'm going to do it now.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Done. Image added.

Comment: If I find citations, I'll put this in an answer:  (1) is a row or an aisle, though some places would lump both sides into that unit, (2) is a shelf.  So you might say "halfway down the third row, on the 5th shelf" or "second aisle, halfway down the left side, on the 5th shelf."

Comment: @Hellion Thanks, But I believe `aisle` is an empty place that is created by two of rows. Am I right?

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar yes, that's true, but the shelving can be considered the side of the aisle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're called **"gondolas"** – like the boats in Venice – or, *gondola shelves*. AmE

See https://www.stampsstorefixtures.com/gondolabuilder.

Comment: The link that you put is not working

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar - The answer is still correct - Thanks  again for the downvote

Comment: I don't have reputation for downvotes yet. The minimum is 125. I didn't downvote you. :)

Comment: +1.  I am pleased to discover retail operations has domain specific classification of the form factors of shelving.  The OP asked "in Supermarkets".  This is a useful and informative answer.

Answer (score 0):

The numbered parts of supermarkets (that is, the lines between the shelves that are numbered are standardly called ‘aisles’.